# Could not find the 'Cropper' processor in any of these paths: lib/paperclip, lib/paperclip_processors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip, cropper

I had to include the paperclip_processors directory
I get cropper processor not found error. I follow railscast and doing exactly like that

```
module Paperclip
class Cropper < Thumbnail
def transformation_command
  if crop_command
    crop_command + super.sub(/ -crop \S+/, '')
  else
    super
  end
end

def crop_command
  target = @attachment.instance
  if target.cropping?
    " -crop '#{target.crop_w.to_i}x#{target.crop_h.to_i}+#{target.crop_x.to_i}+#{target.crop_y.to_i}'"
  end
end
end
end
```

in applicatio.rb

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{Rails.root}/lib)  
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{Rails.root}/lib/paperclip_processors)
```

and user.rb

```
has_attached_file :profile_picture, {
styles: {
  original: "1400>",
  medium: "400>",
  thumb: "150>"
},
:processors => [:cropper],
storage: :s3,
s3_credentials: S3_CREDENTIALS,
```

}

Answer (score 0):

When I was developing on my mac I didn't face this issue, but when I deployed to an EC2 Ubuntu instance I got this error.

When I changed the caps on the file name of the processor it worked. For example if you have the file name as "Cropper.rb" rename it to "cropper.rb" and try.

my environment is:
Ruby 2.3.1
Rails 4.2.4
Paperclip 5.0.0